# How to combine filenames in gulp to use as arguments for a command line tool?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

How would I create a Gulpfile.js that was able to (f.i) pass the paths of all cpp files in a certain directory to g++?

The generated shell command should look something like this:

```
g++ -o myprog.exe file1.cpp file2.cpp
```

and I am thinking of a gulp solution that might look like this:

```
gulp.task('compile-cpps',function (){
    gulp.src("src/*.cpp")
       .pipe(listify-filenames())
       .pipe(shell_cmd("g++ -o myprog.exe <$filenames$>"))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't actually using gulp streams, just bypass them:

```
var glob = require('glob'),
    exec = require('child_process').exec;

gulp task('compile-cpps', function(gulpCallback) {
    glob('src/*.cpp', function(files) {
        files = files.map(function(f) { return '"'+f+'"'; }).join(' ');
        exec('g++ -o my-prog.exe '+files, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
            gulpCallback(error);
        });
    });
});
```

This lists all files that match your `glob`, wraps each filename in quotes (to allow for spaces), then spawns a new process for `g++` with the filename appended.  On completion, the [async callback for gulp is handled](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#async-task-support).

You can either log or output the stdout and stderr from your process.  If you'd rather handle the process in a streaming manner, replace `exec` with [`spawn` and attach to the events](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options):

```
var glob = require('glob'),
    spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

gulp task('compile-cpps', function(gulpCallback) {
    glob('src/*.cpp', function(files) {
        spawn('g++', ['-o', 'my-prog.exe'].concat(files))
            .on('close', function(code) {
                gulpCallback(code);
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good sulution. But I miss the elegance of the usual gulp way. Maybe a plugin is order to integrate this better with gulp? Because I wonder how this could work with watch or caching.

Comment: I'm not sure the issue with watches.  If you need to build everything at once, you can use `gulp.watch('src/*.cpp', ['compile-cpps'])`.  If you can build each file one-by-one, you can use the existing [`gulp-exec`](https://npmjs.org/package/gulp-exec/) plugin.

Comment: That is exactly the point. I dont want to build everything at once. Think of a huge cpp project (llvm for example). And I chose an example that creates an aggrate of multiple files (actually an aggregate of their filenames) on purpose, and not a one-by-one pipeline of file contents.